# How to pull info from within a text file - using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to pull information out of a text file which is always after the third comma but before the 4th eg I need tht,1,2,THIS INFO,444

then save this into a file .txt

is this possible using a .bat

Answer (score 0):

#### I need to pull information out of a text file from between the 3rd and 4th `,`

```
tht,1,2,THIS INFO,444
```

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=4 delims=," %%i in (myfile.txt) do echo %%i > newfile.txt
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Input file is `myfile.txt`
- Output file is `newfile.txt`

Example output:

```
F:\test>type myfile.txt
tht,1,2,THIS INFO,444

F:\test>test

F:\test>type newfile.txt
THIS INFO

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
for /f "delims=, tokens=3" %i in (myfile.txt) do echo %i
```

Thanks for the correction, (in comments below.)

Comment: just to note: if using that in a batch-file, double every percent-sign.

Comment: Did you actually try the command? There are several mistakes in it. Try `for /f "tokens=4 delims=," %i in (myfile.txt) do echo %i` (tested and working)